# Find a specific value multiple times in a time series

Tags: r, time-series, detection

I am trying to find a specific value, in this case 0, multiple times in a time series. The data looks like this

`structure(list(time = c(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 44.9, 45.9, 46.9,  47.9, 48.9, 49.9, 50.8, 51.8, 52.8, 53.7, 54.6, 55.6, 56.5, 57.5,  58.5, 59.5, 60.5, 61.5, 62.5, 63.5, 64.5, 65.5, 66.5, 67.5, 68.5,  69.5, 70.5, 71.5, 72.5, 73.5, 74.5, 75.5, 76.4, 77.3, 78.3, 79.3,  80.3, 81.2, 82.2, 83.2, 84.2, 85.2, 86.2, 87.2, 88.2, 89.2, 90.2,  91.2, 92.2, 93.2, 94.2, 95.2, 96.2, 97.2, 98.2, 99.2, 100.2,  101.2, 102, 103, 103.9, 104.9, 105.9, 106.8, 107.8, 108.8, 109.8,  110.8, 111.8, 112.8, 113.8, 114.4, 114.9, 115.8, 116.8, 117.8,  118.8, 119.8), value = c(33.6, 33.6, 33.6, 33.6, 33.6,  33.6, 34, 34, 34.4, 34.72, 29.12, 34.8, 19.04, 30.32, 1.36, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.48, 28.64, 32, 32, 32,  32, 32, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.68, 31.12, 32, 32,  31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 32, 32,  32, 2.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.16, 32, 31.92, 31.92, 38.8,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -83L), class = "data.frame")`

The problem is I want to find the times of the first zeros in `value` appearing for some time. So the process is like: If `value` goes down to zero give me the time for this point in `time`, then if `value` went up for `time` and then goes down again to zero give me the time for this point in `time` etc...
Plotting the data should help to understand the problem.

So the result should look like this for `time`: 54.6, 76.4, 102, 114.4

Edit: I don't know if it is important but the original data is in a data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this. Here I took the cumulative sum of values equal to zero, then, evaluated the "run length." Maybe easiest to understand running the code piece by piece working inside-out. In a nutshell, I used `rle` and `cumsum` to solve.

```
o <- structure(list(time = c(40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 44.9, 45.9, 46.9,  47.9, 48.9, 49.9, 50.8, 51.8, 52.8, 53.7, 54.6, 55.6, 56.5, 57.5,  58.5, 59.5, 60.5, 61.5, 62.5, 63.5, 64.5, 65.5, 66.5, 67.5, 68.5,  69.5, 70.5, 71.5, 72.5, 73.5, 74.5, 75.5, 76.4, 77.3, 78.3, 79.3,  80.3, 81.2, 82.2, 83.2, 84.2, 85.2, 86.2, 87.2, 88.2, 89.2, 90.2,  91.2, 92.2, 93.2, 94.2, 95.2, 96.2, 97.2, 98.2, 99.2, 100.2,  101.2, 102, 103, 103.9, 104.9, 105.9, 106.8, 107.8, 108.8, 109.8,  110.8, 111.8, 112.8, 113.8, 114.4, 114.9, 115.8, 116.8, 117.8,  118.8, 119.8), value = c(33.6, 33.6, 33.6, 33.6, 33.6,  33.6, 34, 34, 34.4, 34.72, 29.12, 34.8, 19.04, 30.32, 1.36, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.48, 28.64, 32, 32, 32,  32, 32, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.68, 31.12, 32, 32,  31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 31.6, 32, 32,  32, 2.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.16, 32, 31.92, 31.92, 38.8,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -83L), class = "data.frame")

tmp <- rle(cumsum(o$value == 0))$lengths

o[cumsum(tmp)[tmp > 1] + 1,"time"]
[1]  54.6  76.4 102.0 114.4
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it works! In my original data there might be something like: 0 0 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5. The problem is the zero in the middle, it is just a very short time and a low value. Is it possible to ignore something like this?

Comment: Sure. I think this should work: If your threshold is at least 3 consecutive zeros then change `o[cumsum(tmp)[tmp > 1] + 1,"time"]` to `o[cumsum(tmp)[tmp > 3] + 1,"time"]`

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse` and `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
o %>% 
     group_by(grp = rleid(value == 0)) %>% 
     filter(value == 0) %>% 
     group_by(grp) %>%
     slice(1) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     select(time)
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#   time
#  <dbl>
#1  54.6
#2  76.4
#3 102  
#4 114.
```